# React form initialization with data in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have edit reactive-form. In ngOnInit() I'm trying to initialize the form with server data. First I will call api and then the data is set. But what is happening is that before array receives data from api, the form get initialized. Because of that I am getting an error

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Markup:

```
 <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
       <h2>Users</h2>
       <div class="form-controls">
         <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput placeholder="User name" type="email" formControlName="username">
           <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && formControl.username.errors">
           <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.username.errors.required || formControl.username.hasError('email')"> * Valid
            Email
            required</mat-error>

          </mat-error>
         </mat-form-field>
       </div>
       <div class="form-controls">
         <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput placeholder="First name" type="text" formControlName="firstname">
           <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && formControl.firstname.errors">
             <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.firstname.errors.required"> * First Name required</mat-error>

           </mat-error>
         </mat-form-field>

       </div>
       <div class="button-section">
               <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="closeDailog()" id="cancel"><i class="material-icons">clear</i>Cancel</button>
               <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit" id="create"><i class="material-icons">done</i>Edit</button>

       </div>
 </form>
```

Code: `component.ts`:

```
 ngOnInit(){
  this.UserServiceObj.getUserDetailOnID(this.userId).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  // this.initializeDetail();
  this.userDetail = res;

  });

  this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: [this.userDetail['username'], [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  firstname: [this.userDetail['firstname'], Validators.required])};
}
```

Comment: Is that all in one method of `component.ts`?

Comment: Its there but I added only needed code

Comment: Initialize the form when you have the data when the observable emits. In subscribe

Comment: @AluanHaddad Tried,placed form initialization inside subscribe .form is not initialized with values and also got same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not run the code but:
`subscribe` is asyc and it will execute when your service returns.
Immediately after setting up a subscription you try to set properties from `this.userDetails` that at the point of time can be `undefined`

You can try something like this or map your reply to an Observable which you can than subscribe to in your template with ngIf and async pipe https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

```js
async ngOnInit() {
  this. userDetail  = await this.UserServiceObj.getUserDetailOnID(this.userId).toPromisse();

  this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: [this.userDetail['username'], [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  firstname: [this.userDetail['firstname'], Validators.required])};

}
```

Regarding the other part you can find a working form below it should help you to fix yours

```html
<div class="p-3">
  <p>Please enter your username and password.</p>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-3" (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector:    'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls:   ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent {

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl(''),
  });

  constructor(private userService: UserService,
              private modal: NgbActiveModal) {
  }

  login() {
    this.userService.login();
  }

  close() {
    this.modal.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: i have another issue.I have 2 button one is cancel and another one submit .when I click cancel reactive-form submits..

Comment: sorry I don't see any button the code above,

use (click) on the button to provide a callback that you would like to use with each of your buttons.

Note that a form can have only one submit button, another one you can provide with type='button' and a 'click' handler

see here: https://angular.io/guide/forms