# MeanStack: conflict on editing feature'_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've seen solutions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350530/performing-an-update-on-the-path-id-would-modify-the-immutable-field-idhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350530/performing-an-update-on-the-path-id-would-modify-the-immutable-field-id) and in others, but I did follow the instructions and I'm still getting the error. I understand all the logic, id's can't be replaced, they are immutable, but in my mean stack app, the error persists. The code:

Node route

```
  router.put("/:id" ,(req, res, next) => {
  const note = new Note({
    _id:req.body.id,
    project: req.body.project,
    note: req.body.note,
    date:req.body.date,

  });
  Note.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, note).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Update successful!" });
  });
});
```

Front End edit component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.notesForm=this.fb.group({
      note:['', Validators.required],
      project:['', Validators.required],
      date:[null,Validators.required]
    })
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paraMap:ParamMap)=>{
      if(paraMap.has('noteId')){
        this.mode='edit';
        this.noteId= paraMap.get('noteId');
        this.note=this.notePadService.getNote(this.noteId)
        .subscribe(noteData=>{
          this.note = {id: noteData._id, note: noteData.note, date: noteData.date, project: noteData.project};
        })
      }else{
        this.mode='create';
        this.noteId=null;
      }
    })
    this.getProjects();
  }
  onSubmit(){
    if(this.mode==='create'){
      this.notePadService.submitNotes(this.notesForm.value)
      console.log(this.notesForm.value);
      this.router.navigate(['/notes-listing'])
    }else{
      this.notePadService.updateNote(
        this.noteId,this.notesForm.value
      )
    }
  }
```

Service:

```
    getNote(id:string){
      return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/api/notes/'+id)
    }

updateNote(id:string,note:Notes){
    this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/api/notes/'+id,note)
    .subscribe(response=>console.log(response))
}
```

Also I cant pre-populate the reactive form with the values to edit:

```
  <label>Select a Project</label>
  <select (change)="test($event.target.value)" formControlName="project"
    class="form-control">
    <option
    *ngFor="let p of projects"
    [value]="p.name">{{ p.name }}</option>
  </select>
<!------->
<label for="notes">Note</label>
<textarea class="form-control"  formControlName="note" type="text" rows="4"></textarea>
<div class="input-group">
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="warn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I click the edit button (in another component), I get the correct URL but no values, and onsubmit, the backend crashes:

```
http://localhost:4200/edit/601ec21882fa6af20b454a8d
```

Can someone help me out? I'm very confused and I cant understand the error since I've done everything the other posts suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `updateOne` you already pass as the first argument the `id` that should be updated. As second argument you pass `note` that should contain only the properties that will be updated, but not `_id` itself:

```
  const note = {
    project: req.body.project,
    note: req.body.note,
    date:req.body.date,
  };
```

Comment: sorry, but the error persists...is that something to do with the pre populated form (because it is not)

Comment: I edited my answer, pass only an object `note`, don't create a new instance of a `Note`. when you instantiate `new Note` will likely have a `_id` field regardless

Comment: thank you! if not an abuse, how can I pre populate the reactive form with the values to edit?

Comment: @Mellville here are some approaches for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686147/set-reactive-form-after-data-loaded-async-angular-5

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272081/react-form-initialization-with-data-in-angular-7  https://coryrylan.com/blog/using-angular-forms-with-async-data